# amcharts Export with Meteor + React (JSX)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, amcharts

I am using Meteor + React(JSX) with amCharts.
I have the charts rendering the issue I am facing is that the export functionality is not working.

I receive the following error messages in the browser:

```
fabric.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jszip.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
FileSaver.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
xlsx.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

On line 1 for each of those files I see: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

I believe the issue has something to do with the way meteor loads the files but am not quite sure.

At the top of my component I have:

```
import "amcharts3-export";
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AmCharts from 'amcharts3-react';
```

The amCharts config looks as following:

```
const config = {
            "type": "serial",
            "theme": "light",
            "categoryField": "year",
            "valueAxes": [
                {
                  "id": "ValueAxis-1",
                  "title": "Payback"
                }
            ],
            "animation": false,
            "graphs": 
                  [{
                      "type": "smoothedLine",
                      "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[year]]:[[value]]",
                      "bullet": "round",
                      "id": "AmGraph-1",
                      "title": "graph 1",
                      "valueField": "value",
                      "fillColorsField": "lineColor",
                      "lineColorField": "lineColor",
                      "fillAlphas": 0.3,
                  }],
            "dataProvider": this.state.lineItems,
            "export": {
              "enabled": true,
              "libs": { 
                "autoLoad": false,
                "path": "../libs/" 
              },
              "menu": [{
                "class": "export-main",
                "menu": [ "JPG" ]
              }]
            }
        }
```

Any advice would be much appreaciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm not sure why it works. I copied the export js files into public/libs folder. Which did take away the errors but not sure why and if duplicate copies of the js will be bundled - will need to investigate. For the export component to work I then have these imports:

```
import 'amcharts3-export';
import 'amcharts3-export/export.css';
import AmCharts from 'amcharts3-react';
```

And I render the chart with:

```
render () {
        return (
            <div id={this.props.tileid} style={{width: '100%', height: this.props.height.toString()+'px'}} >
                <AmCharts.React
                    ref="chartref"
                    {...this.chart}
                    dataProvider={this.props.data}
                    key={this.props.tile._id}
                />
            </div>
        );
```

where `this.chart` is my chart setup obj.

This chart obj should have:

```
"export": {
        "enabled": true,
        "libs": { "path": "/libs/" },
        ...
 }
```

I also import 'amcharts3/amcharts/gauge.js'; when working with other chart types.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.

When you say you copied the files into public/libs folder, did you copy the whole amcharts3-export folder into root/public/libs or only specific files? Also did you remove from node_modules the amchart3-export module?

Comment: Yes copied all of the folders and files in `root/node_modules/amcharts3-export/libs/*` to `root/public/libs/*` . I also have the files in `node_modules` and I think it is only loaded as required as files in the public folder is served as assets if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I did exactly that. Still getting same error though. I have these imports in my graph component:

import "amcharts3-export";
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AmCharts from 'amcharts3-react';

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the /libs/ path variable.

Comment: Thanks with moving the files to the libs folder and adding path variable it is now working. For now this is good, but meteor staff should figure out why we need this workaround.

thanks again

Comment: I think that if amCharts-export was defined properly with an npm modules and dependencies this should not be a problem. amCharts should really publish a proper npm version.

Comment: In react, how did you 'wait' until the amChart component is fully loaded?
I tried in componentDidMount but it was not completely reliable

Comment: I set the properties in a var the constructor and use react-komposer to wait for the data ready. Then I render the chart and data when all is ready

Comment: What is 'amcharts3-export' ? I thought that export plugin comes with all needed libs